# Save data frame containing a list column as a " delimited txt file

Tags: r

I have a data frame of which one column is a list; e.g.

```
x = c("Benny", "Johnny")
y1 = c("Product 1","Product 3","Product 4")
y2 = c("Product 1","Product 2")
myList = vector("list", 2)
myList[[1]] = y1
myList[[2]] = y2

productSales = data.frame(x, cbind(myList), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(productSales) = c("Name", "Product")
```

I succeed to save `productSales` as a `txt` file through

```
capture.output(twoDifferentPfFlags, file = "result.txt")
```

My problem with this method, however, is that columns are not delimited with `"` as one would get using `write.table`.

Is there a way to generate `"` delimited results table when a column of a data frame contains a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not aware of a builtin way of saving list columns. In your particular case, you could convert the list column to a character column by pasting the values:

```
productSales$Product = unlist(lapply(productSales$Product, paste, collapse = ', '))
```

Afterwards, you can use `write.table` (or a more modern equivalent such as `readr::write_csv`).